# how to know, in which line the value of a JS object property was changed

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, browser, watch

I am using the object.watch method.

```
    obj[i].position.watch("x", function (id, oldval, newval) {
        console.log( "Object " + id + " changed from " + oldval + " to " + newval );
        return newval;
    });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fwatch#Examples

How do I find out, where in my code(which .js file, which line) this value is getting changed?

Comment: Try adding the line `debugger;` and inspect the call stack - or just simply set a breakpoint on the `console.log()` line - or you need to access this information programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the line `debugger;` and inspect the call stack - or just simply set a breakpoint on the `console.log()` line.